# Chrome App, Bootstrap Icons, how to load Glyphicons Halflings.woff

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-face, google-chrome-app

I'm building a chrome packaged app, and want to use Bootstrap.

Bootstrap has a Glyph Halflings font that offers some icons.

When I include boostrap.css, I never see the font files loaded in the network tab of dev tools.

Reading other posts, I tried this, but it was not successful that I could see in my app or network tab.  The fonts are never loaded:

```
/* Assist for Bootstrap icons */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAFsYABEAAAAAoU...VLmWK4AAA==") format('woff');
}
```

also tried mime-types `application/font-woff` and `application/x-font-woff`
also tried:

```
src: data-uri(~'@{fonts}@{glyphicons-halflings-regular}.woff') format('woff')
src: data-uri(~'@{fonts}@{glyphicons-halflings-regular}.woff') format('woff')
```

My font is in /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff  ttf, oet, and svg are also options.

I am testing this by looking for the icon, and looking for any traffic in the network tab of dev tools.

How are fonts included in a Chrome packaged app?

**Solution**

There was no problem with Chrome.  I was using the wrong HTML (BS2) with the CSS (BS3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the mime type to `application/font-woff` as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url("data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAFsY....==") format('woff');
}
```

The above should work, see also: http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff

Less code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: data-uri(~'@{icon-font-path}@{icon-font-name}.woff') format('woff')
}
```

Notice that you also will have to set the other font related classes:

```
// Catchall baseclass
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

// Individual icons
.glyphicon-asterisk               { &:before { content: "\2a"; } }
// and so on
```

Comment: Hey Bass, sorry to be an idiot, but it's not working for me.  I updated the question with some more things I tried.  I'm using bootstrap 3's bootstrap.css.  Doesn't that handle the rest of the CSS and I just need to fix the font-face?

Comment: if you use the default CSS the `icon-font-path` is set to `../fonts` which means that if your CSS is in `{root}/css/boostrap.less` you font files should be in `{root}/fonts/`. I not sure why you use `data-uri` instead on `url()` for the fonts. But `data-uri` should also work. Maybe you only overwrite the woff by data-uri and load your browser an other font type ealier set by the bootstrap CSS, which point to a file which not exists?

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools' Network tab to see whether requests for the .woff are succeeding. If not, that's your problem.

Comment: @sowbug the no font requests are happening in the browser.  So that's the problem, but how to fix it?

Comment: Ahhh...  Maybe this is for compiling a custom version of bootstrap.css using LESS.  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I set the body tag to use the glyphicon font and it worked.  The problem was my html.  Doh!  Thanks for the help :-)